# IE6 PNG transparency fix for images being used with rotate.php

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using the standard rotate.php script to rotate the header images in my website (drupal 6.10). However the images being used have a transparent background which gets rendered as a dull blue in IE6. I have tried using PNG fix : twinhelix.com , have used modules pngfix and pngbehave .. but to no avail. The website is : [http://www.geek.designbracket.com/][1]

The CSS code fr the header div is :

```
#header {
    background: transparent url(img/banners/rotate.php) no-repeat 0px 0px; /*rotates images in the banners folder */
}
```

Have also tried adding the alphaloader filter to the same div as given under:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='banner_bgimg.png', sizingMethod='scale');
position: relative; z-index: 1;
```

I think I am doing something wrong here . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [IEpngFix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/). I hope it helps.

Comment: tried the IEpngfix ; but it works only if in the src I specify a particular image however .. I m using a php script to fetch the images randomly .. and want each of the images to be displayed correctly ..

Comment: well.. modify the IEpngfix and add dynamically the images to it after you know which one are you going to display.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [PNG Behave!](https://www.drupal.org/project/pngbehave) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> Corrects PNG alpha transparency in IE 5.5 and 6 using css behaviors instead of crawling the DOM.